# monitor mousemove event in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, mousemove

I'm trying to monitor the mouse movement over the application window
so that whenever the mouse moves its coordinates are reflected in two text conrols

Is it possible to do it in XAML only (without code)?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to write code.  Getting mouse position is only doable by calling the Mouse.GetPosition method.  This isn't something you can represent in XAML.